# Simple Bloc Pattern and Network Connection check

Tags: flutter, dart, design-patterns, bloc

Thank you for checking out my question :). I appreciate it!

### What I am trying to do

I am trying to check if the user has an internet connection or not. For this, I use the bloc pattern. I am just starting out and I don't know what to do with these errors.

### What the error messages are

The relevant error-causing widget was:
TestScreen
Testscreen:file//filepath (etc,etc)

Another exception was thrown: Each child must be laid out exactly once.
Another exception was thrown: Updated layout information required for RenderErrorBox NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT to calculate semantics.

Another exception was thrown: Bad state: Future already completed.

I am new and these errors are overwhelming. These errors tell me nothing. I hope you can help me out!

### Code

#### Homescreen

```dart
class HomeScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const HomeScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  static String routeName = '/home';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Homepage'),
        ),
        body: BlocProvider(
          create: (context) => NetworkBloc()..add(ListenConnection()),
          child: TestScreen(),
        ));
  }
}

class TestScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const TestScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: BlocBuilder<NetworkBloc, NetworkState>(
        builder: (context, state) {
          if (state is ConnectionFailure) return Text("No Internet Connection");
          if (state is ConnectionSuccess)
            return Text("You're Connected to Internet");
          else
            return Text("");
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

#### Network Block

```dart
class NetworkBloc extends Bloc<NetworkEvent, NetworkState> {
  NetworkBloc() : super(ConnectionInitial());

  late StreamSubscription _subscription;

  @override
  Stream<NetworkState> mapEventToState(NetworkEvent event) async* {
    if (event is ListenConnection) {
      _subscription = DataConnectionChecker().onStatusChange.listen((status) {
        add(ConnectionChanged(status == DataConnectionStatus.disconnected
            ? ConnectionFailure()
            : ConnectionSuccess()));
      });
    }
    if (event is ConnectionChanged) yield event.connection;
  }

  @override
  Future<void> close() {
    _subscription.cancel();
    return super.close();
  }
}
```

#### Network Event

```dart
abstract class NetworkEvent {}

class ListenConnection extends NetworkEvent {}

class ConnectionChanged extends NetworkEvent {
  NetworkState connection;
  ConnectionChanged(this.connection);
}
```

#### Network State

```dart
abstract class NetworkState {}

class ConnectionInitial extends NetworkState {}

class ConnectionSuccess extends NetworkState {}

class ConnectionFailure extends NetworkState {}
```

I hope you can help me out. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of issues with your code so I'm not sure if I got all of them.

- **You should not call `.add()` if you don't have registered event handler**

```dart
//This is how you should register an event handler

NetworkBloc() : super(ConnectionInitial()) {
  on<ListenConnection>((event, emit) {
    // TODO: implement event handler 
  });
}
```

- **You are overriding a function `mapEventToState()`, when it doesn't override any of inherited methods**

```dart
//@override NO NEED OF OVERRIDE HERE
Stream<NetworkState> mapEventToState(NetworkEvent event) async* {
  if (event is ListenConnection) {
    _subscription = DataConnectionChecker().onStatusChange.listen((status) {
      add(ConnectionChanged(status == DataConnectionStatus.disconnected
        ? ConnectionFailure()
        : ConnectionSuccess()));
    });
  }
  if (event is ConnectionChanged) yield event.connection;
}
```

And I'm not sure if this is intended, but your `mapEventToState()` also never gets called and without any `emit()` methods your UI will never rebuild.

Comment: Hey thanks for your answer. I followed a tutorial. https://burcus.medium.com/flutter-check-continuously-internet-connection-using-bloc-and-stream-9951d9811c8e. 

When I try to emit it gave me the following error: 'The argument type 'ConnectionChanged' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'NetworkState'.

It was intended to not call mapEventToState(). It is written in the tutorial as well.

And when I try to change it to 'on', I cannot have a constructor in it like : ConnectionChanged(connection);

Do you have more advice? Thanks

Comment: @Jay my bad, `ConnectionChanged` is an event so you should not call `.emit()` instead `.add()` in your code was right. And all event handlers are registered in constructor